# How can I grant my aws sftp server access to an Amazon S3 bucket in another AWS account FEDERATED USER

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-transfer-family

I'm adjusting a qas bucket that is accessed by the AWS TRANSFER FAMILY SFTP service from another account (production account), I need to add this qas backup as home of a new user, but for my user the destination bucket (which is in the qas account), does not appear in the selection.

in the destination account, where the bucket is, I have this policy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "BucketPolicyForSFTP",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::**PRODUCTION-ACCOUNT-ID**:root"
        },
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname-qas",
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname-qas/*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "aws:userId": "AROA... **THIS IS A FUNCTION ID**?:*"
            }
        } 
    }
```

I tried to login with my user via console and run in cli: aws sts get-caller-identity --output json

"UserId": "AROA...ID:myuser@mymail",
"Account": "PRODUCTION-ACCOUNT-ID",
"Arn": "arn:aws:sts::PRODUCTION´´ACCOUNTID:assumed-role/AWSReservedSSO_AWSAdministratorAccess_idxxx/myuser@mymail"

I already tried to put this user ID in the permission, as well as my arn in the policy, but when logging in with my federated user in the PRD account, I still can't see the bucket that is in the QAS account when looking for the buckets in the family SFTP transfer configuration

Is it possible to do this with a federated user?

Thank you very much!